# search with dropdown filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

does anyone have an example of a javascript searchbox with a dropdown filter?
so for example i'm looking to create a searchbox for my site and allow users to either search:
"Current Category" or "Whole Site". I could create a combobox and place it next to the input box but i'm trying to see if there is a fancier js way of doing this.

**EDIT:** i don't think i explained very well what i'm looking for.
So, I have an input box to perform searches on my site. What i'd like is to be able to narrow down this searches and make them more specific by providing a filter.
So for example, i want the user to search for "John Doe", but before he must select whether he is going to search in the current category "blog posts" or "whole site".

[image]

Comment: if you are going to downvote me like this, at least comment on why am i being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the chosen plugin might help you: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

It's a select-box replacement with a search feature:

[image: Screenshot of chosen]

If you just need an improved button you might start with the jQueryUi Button:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

[image: Screenshot of splitbutton]

Comment: not exacly what i'm looking for. i have an input box and i'd like to add a small combobox to it so i can select what type of content i want to search

Answer (score 0):

There is so many solutions:
[selectbox | jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/selectbox).
Or just Google "jquery custom select"

Comment: @nmuntz, You are looking for selectbox, aren't you? You just want an sliding down menu with options, where you can select one...

Comment: basically yes, but you are missing the "selectbox" inside an "input" box... its a search input box... user needs to be able to type the text they are looking for and then select where in the site they want to look for it

Comment: @nmuntz, it's not really "inside" the input, it's just next to it. Just give the input only top, left and bottom borders. And to the selectbox only top, right and bottom. And it will look like one input with a selectbox "inside" it.